# LeakCanary - SearchView leaking?

Tags: java, android, leakcanary

I have an activity that has a SearchView in its toolbar, and also hosts 2 Fragments (one that lists past search terms and another that shows the results). After loading that activity and fragments LeakCanary starts showing notifications saying that the Activity and both Fragments have leaked. All three have a similar reports which looks as follows:

[image]

It also starts with something called ReportFragment (a system fragment I guess, whose leak report is also essentially the same as what's posted above):

[image]

I cannot figure out what might be leaking but I was wondering if anybody has ever encountered a similar issue?